# How to show Powerpoint PPT file slide animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, html5-canvas

> Is there any way to show slider animation of PPT File in Webpage.I tried with iframe but its only downloaded the file.

```
<iframe src="test.pptx" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" id="iView" name="iView"></iframe>
```